# JSTL <c:remove not recognized

Tags: jsf, glassfish, jstl

I have tried looking, and its just getting silly.

I am running Glassfish 3.1.1,
JSF version 2
and netbeans 7.0.1

And the following will not work, at all.

> < html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
>        xmlns:c="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core">
>
> *snipped*
>
> < c:remove var="test" scope="session"/>

I know it must be something stupid, this is what netbeans keeps saying:

> The component library Jstl Core doesn't contain component

And in every JSTL tag library I have checked, it does!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `<c:remove>` is originally in the [JSTL](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/jstl/1.1/docs/tlddocs/) library for the legacy JSP view technology. [Facelets](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/javaserverfaces/2.1/docs/vdldocs/facelets/), the successor of JSP, has only a [subset](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/javaserverfaces/2.1/docs/vdldocs/facelets/c/tld-summary.html) of the JSTL tags redefinied (JSP tags doesn't work in Facelets, they have been ported/rewritten). The `<c:remove>` is not among them.

Your concrete problem has to be solved differently. As the concrete functional requirement is unclear, I can't answer that in detail. But I *guess* that you actually need a JSF `@ViewScoped` or a CDI `@ConversationScoped` bean and store the desired property in there. It'll then be removed when the view scope or the conversation scope ends. Those scopes are well definied and lies in between the request and session scope. See also [How to choose the right bean scope?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7031885/how-to-choose-the-right-bean-scope)

Comment: Thank you, my concrete problem will be solved another way, this would just have made it much much much simpler and more efficient.